# I am using flutter native splash package for splash screen in my app

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

It is working properly in all devices including web except android 12 devices. I tried too many ways to figure it out, but am not able to find solution. If anyone knows solution please reply as soon as possible.

The problem is in android 12 devices, logo which I have used isn't showing.In other devices it working perfectly.

Here I am attaching my pubspec.yaml dev_dependencies info:-

```
dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
  sdk: flutter


  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.3+1
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter_native_splash:
  image: assets/images/splash.png
  color: "#23AA49"
  android: true
  android12: true
  ios: true

  android_12:
    image: assets/images/splash.png
    color: "#23AA49"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for android:exported**

Make these changes
android:exported="true"
Update targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion

you can refer to this
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/migration

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Go to Your android->app when you noticed that build.gradle file just open it and. modify it it contains targetsdkversion and compilesdkversion aslo

[click on this link you will show one image then modify your puspec.yamel file  i have no such reputation so i can not embeded image in post right now after 10 i get that right so you have to click on this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nQXL.png)

Comment: I tried...It isn't working

Comment: ohk wait i will give you proper guidence

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVozO.png)[Follow this picture you can see build.gradle file go there and then follow second picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2Ocs.png)

[search this potion of file and modified it as per my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roz1p.png)

[then in same file modified this line also](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSxXc.png)

Comment: click on this link and you will see the picture

Comment: I had done it before.

Comment: I had done it again as you told step by step still isn't working.

Comment: Did you run flutter clean and flutter pub get ?

Comment: yes, I had do that